# How to read .xpt format file from the Azure ADLS blob container and convert to csv format

Tags: python, azure-databricks, azure-data-lake-gen2

Downloaded the .xpt format file from the URL  to the blob container in  Databricks - Python notebook.

In the below code - 'example.xpt' is the local file. How to read the .xpt format file from the blob container?

```
import xport.v56

with open('example.xpt', 'rb') as f:

    library = xport.v56.load(f)
```

Appreciate any inputs. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering you have already installed the library `xport` in your cluster and *mounted your ADLS blob container*, you follow the steps given below:

- Use the same code, except the path will be the `.xpt` file present in your blob container.

```
import xport.v56

with open('/dbfs/mnt/repro/ALQY_F.XPT', 'rb') as f:
    # '/dbfs/mnt/repro/' refers to the mount point i.e., to ADLS blob container.
    library = xport.v56.load(f)
```

- The **library** object is of type `class 'xport.v56.Library'`. `library` has an attribute **`values`** which returns an *iterable* object.
- Use the following code to write the required data to `csv` format in specified destination

```
for data in library.values():

    print(type(data)) # <class 'xport.v56.Member'>

    print(dir(data)) # use to check all the possible attributes that can be used on this object

    data.to_csv("/dbfs/mnt/repro/op.csv") #writes as csv to your blob container.
```

[image]

***Without Mounting:***

- With your client_id, tenant_id and client_secret, set up configurations for your ADLS storage using following command.

```
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<adls_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "OAuth")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<adls_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.azurebfs.oauth2.ClientCredsTokenProvider")
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<adls_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", client_id)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<adls_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", client_secret)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<adls_name>.dfs.core.windows.net", "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant_id>/oauth2/token")
```

- Now you can access your data lake storage container using `abfss`. Using `abfss://data@blb0708.dfs.core.windows.net/example.xpt` directly with `open()` does not work.

[image]

- Hence, use `dbutils.fs.cp()` to copy the file from abfss to DBFS.

```
#copy from datalake to DBFS

dbutils.fs.cp("abfss://data@<adls_name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<file_name>","dbfs:/<required_path>")
```

- Now you can follow the procedure provided above to create csv from the data of xpt (save csv to dbfs and move to ADLS if required)

Comment: Saideep - Thanks for the quick response. Mounting is not allowed in my project for security reasons. Is there any alternative to read the file. Tried with BlobClient.from_blob_url(blob_url=adls_file_dest_path + file_name, credential=credential)# Azure Datalake authorization
credential = ClientSecretCredential(tenant_id, client_id, client_secret).

Comment: with the above getting TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not BlobClient

Comment: You can not use BlobClient object with `open()` directly, hence the error. As indicated in the message, it has to be a path of type str, bytes or os.PathLike object

Comment: Any alternative suggestions?

Comment: added additional approach as `Without Mounting` section

Comment: Thanks. It worked. It is similar to the "wget" in the %sh  in the notebook.